# What regex should be applied when selecting text between unknown XML tags but not the tags themselves?

Tags: regex, select, tags

As the title suggests e.g.

```
<unknownTag>Select this only</unknownTag>
<anotherUnknownTag>Select this too</anotherUnknownTag>
```

To select:
- Select this only
- Select this too

A brief explanation on separate parts would be nice too if possible.

Comment: What language are you doing this in? There is a better way I'm sure besides using regular expressions.

Comment: @hwnd I am using a text based editor and need to do only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex.

```
(?!<.+?>)([^<>]+?)(?=</.+?>)
```

Comment: This selects the text and the tags. I need just the text inside the tags and not the tags themselves. I am using a simple text based editor to select via regex.

Comment: @user3197788, check out my eidt

Comment: @AmitJoki do you need to escape the forward slash in the lookahead?

Comment: @deanosaur, I suppose no, because OP is using a simple text editor and not any language